# How to access the Check Dialog in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm using pgAdmin 4 and have used the ERD tool to create all tables, relationships and constraints so far.

I'm trying to add a check constraint via the dialogs (https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/check_dialog.html) but don't seem to be able to.

I'm using the pgerd file to generate the SQL required to generate my tables, which is why I'd like to keep everything in that file.

This question [How to Add a Check Constraint in a Table in pgadmin 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758143/how-to-add-a-check-constraint-in-a-table-in-pgadmin-4) seems to show different options to what I see.

[image: Screen capture of table options]

(I don't have the check option with the constraints tab)

Can anyone advise or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are not able to access the check dialog options when using the pgAdmin 4 erd tool

If you are not using the erd tool, you can access the check dialog options tab as stated by [kashyap-neeraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9372171/kashyap-neeraj) in their answer
[How to Add a Check Constraint in a Table in pgadmin 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758143/how-to-add-a-check-constraint-in-a-table-in-pgadmin-4#answer-55758312)

(right click the table in the pgAdmin browser (the left column) and select properties)